# Cocoa: How do you make the background of an IKImageBrowserView transparent?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, calayer, transparent, ikimagebrowserview

How do you make the background of an IKImageBrowserView transparent? There seems to be no background color option in interface builder.

What I've tried:

I've never used Core Animation, but I saw IKImageBrowserView has a setBackgroundLayer method, so I tried  the following, which had no effect:

```
CALayer* layer = [CALayer layer];
[layer setFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000)];
[layer setBackgroundColor: CGColorCreateGenericRGB(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[browser setBackgroundLayer: layer];
```

Here's the class reference for [IKImageBrowserView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/IKImageBrowserView).

Comment: CALayer has no setBackgroundColor method (the compiler should have told you that).  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: peelman: Yes it has. It has a `backgroundColor` property, which means it has a `backgroundColor` getter and (since the property is readwrite) a `setBackgroundColor:` setter. Remember that property access (e.g., `layer.backgroundColor = …`) is exactly equivalent to—i.e., generates the same code as—a message expression (such as the `[layer setBackgroundColor:…]` from the question). Also, this is a Mac question; beware of API differences between Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

Comment: Max: You also leaked that CGColor object. Core Graphics follows the Core Foundation memory-management rules: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Key Value Coding.  See: [IKImageBrowserView's View Options Section](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/IKImageBrowserView/IKImageBrowserView_Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004708-CH3-SW75)

```
[_imageBrowser setValue:[NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.0] forKey:IKImageBrowserBackgroundColorKey];
```

[Source](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/196347-change-background-color-of-ikimagebrowserview.html).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I called that in awakeFromNib from my IKImageBrowserView's controller and it worked.

Comment: While this *does* work, if you set the background color to a transparent color, the imageBrowserView will no longer draw a selection highlight around selected images, no matter WHAT color you set for the IKImageBrowserSelectionColorKey value. From what I can find, a transparent background eliminates the possibility of selection highlights.